# how to compare columns of different dataframes?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

data frame 1

```
Team      region
xxxx       ppl
yyyy       olk
zzzz       ppl
xyxy       ioj
yzyz       olk
xzxz       ioj
```

datframe 2

```
players     Team      
 chin       xxxx      
 shan       yyyy       
 fav        zzzz       
 janb      xyxy       
  jj      yzyz       
  nbhg     xzxz       
  ggdfg    okk
  jhjuf    kkdu
  hgdf     xyxy
```

if dataframe 1 Team == dataframe 2 then print region.

Required output should be:

```
players     Team    region    
 chin       xxxx     ppl     
 shan       yyyy     olk     
 fav        zzzz     ppl  
 janb       xyxy     ioj  
  jj        yzyz     olk  
  nbhg      xzxz     ioj  
  hgdf      xyxy
```

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
df2.combine_first(df1)

   Team players region
0  xxxx    chin    ppl
1  yyyy    shan    olk
2  zzzz     fav    ppl
3  xyxy    janb    ioj
4  yzyz      jj    olk
5  xzxz    nbhg    ioj
6   okk   ggdfg    NaN
7  kkdu   jhjuf    NaN
8  xyxy    hgdf    NaN
```